# MATLAB - use a string to set the title of a graph

Tags: matlab

I'm writing a MATLAB program that reads in a title from the user to set on a graph...

```
t = input('Please enter a title for the graph: ', 's');
```

I then want to set the title of my plot to `t`. I can't seem to get it to work...

```
title(t)    %# returns ??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Why is this downvoted, is beyond me ... +1 to counter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure in your session you have no variable called `title` masking the `title()` function

```
» whos
  Name       Size     Bytes  Class     Attributes

  t          1x1          2  char                
  title      1x1          8  double              <<<<---- you dont want this!
```

Comment: Is there a way one could get a list of all reserved words, like this one, somewhere ? Just so, as a reference of what one should avoid ?

Comment: I do have this...

  title               1x4                 8  char 

How do I eliminate this? Many thanks!

Comment: @Idigas: Another way to check if a name `foo` is already used for a built-in function is to try `help foo` first and see if it returns anything.

Comment: @Idigas: If you are using the Matlab built-in editor, the keywords are easy to spot - they are the ones in bright blue :)

Comment: Something I don't get about Matlab is how does it do naming deconflictioin. Why should he address the variable `title` rather then the method `title()`?

Comment: @CuriousMe: See this http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/function-precedence-order.html

Comment: Oh, same here! Matlab stinks! It should return an error or at least a warning when the user tries to overwrite a function.